# how do I detect if assertions are turned on in the JVM?

Tags: java, assertion

I want the first line of my Java program output to print whether assertions are turned on.  How do I do this?

**Edit: An additional requirement is that the program should not terminate before doing useful work.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try {
  assert false;
  System.out.println("Assertions disabled.");
}
catch(AssertionError ae) {
  System.out.println("Assertions enabled.");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this? I don't know Java, but I think this may work:

```
try {
    assert false;
    System.out.println("assertions are disabled");
} catch (AssertionError e) {
    System.out.println("assertions are enabled");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A better performing solution (that does not throw exceptions) is:

```
boolean assertionsEnabled = false;
assert (assertionsEnabled = true);
```